# Using vectors in iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, cocos2d-iphone, vector-graphics

I'm working on a simple iOS game that's always drawing 5 to 10 layers of 32bit png images which requires enough memory to crash on the ipod touch 4g when retina enabled. On other devices it works just fine. I'm not even getting memory warnings. So I was trying with lower quality images, like RGB5_A1 format, but it looks really bad because I need alpha transparency and lots of gradients.

Since all the images are exports from Illustrator I was thinking that maybe i could just export a vector image and draw in on iOS. From what i was researching hardly anyone tried this and the only option I've come across was to implement a SVG parser for Quartz.

Did I miss anything?
Also I'm worried about performance, but I couldn't find any benchmarks.

Comment: I think you should start optmizing your code. If an iTouch with retina display can't handle it you are doing something wrong. Even games like SupCom2 which are far more complicated than your game don't use that much ram

Comment: Webkit has support for SVG.  I think you should look at that to see if it can support your needs.

Comment: @Antwan van Houdt, JeremyP I have 1 texture with 2048x2048px, and two 2048x1024px. The app is simple but it has a lot of content, because it's a configurator for avatars and it needs really clear gradients and transparancy

Comment: dude, 2048px, what are you thinking? That is way too big. The iphone screen has a max resolution of 640x960 and the ipad somewhere around 1024xsomething

Comment: I use texture atlas with cocos2d, it's not just one image on those textures, but many that get combined in one image depending on what the user chooses

Comment: you can split up the big resolution images into small one and then combine them to show it in proper way through coding. That may use less ram i guess :) if I am wrong, please correct me :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing specifics of your game, I'm going to make a few assumptions based on normal use...

You are not going to want to use straight vector graphics for this.  Stick with your raster graphics.

If you are talking about 32 bit color space for your PNG images, then you need to scale back.  iOS uses 24 bit images and that includes 8 bits each for red, green, blue, and alpha.  As it stands, you have an extra byte for every pixel shown.

If you are using Adobe products, import the Illustrator file into Photoshop and use the "Save for Web..." option.  Choose PNG-24 and you'll be all set.

Comment: Red, green, blue, and alpha are four channels, each of which have eight bits. That's 32 in total. ;)

Comment: Yeah, where is my head?  Photoshop's PNG export preset is called PNG-24.  Hmmm...  The rest of the post still stands though.  Should not have a performance issue.